# How to get proper Z position of a gameObject when using ScreenToWorldPoint?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I thought I previously had a solution to the problem but it seems that it isn't working as well as it should. Basically, I want to move a gameObject in 3D using the mouse while keeping the Z position the same. If I click and drag the gameObject, it should follow the cursor around without changing the depth of its position.

The code that I had was this:

```
screenSpace = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
mousePosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenSpace.z);
mouseInWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
```

This worked fairly well, but the depth changed ever so slightly every time I moved the object. Why doesn't Unity work if I just do:

```
mousePosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, gameObject.transform.position.z);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of potential causes for this, but the most common would be there's a Rigidbody or Collider enabled that is interacting in some form with the environment that is causing the target object to move.

Try and set the mousePosition as 0:

```
mousePosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 0);
```

If this works fine, then there is some form of interference either via the Physics system or another component etc that is changing the Z position.

Bear in mind that manually modifying an objects position depends heavily on when you update it.

Feel free to update me with more information if this is not the case, and I'll try to get back to you.

Comment: Sorry, I might've stated the problem a bit weirdly. Let me try and explain. If I put the z as transform.position.z, then the object does keep its z position. However, its x and y coordinates are not in line with where the mouse is, so the object is always a set distance away from the mouse.

Comment: Ah I see! That's due to some simple math, since the mouse is expecting a z position that is different to the one you've got.

Comment: Forgot to reply, to fix this I'll need a little more context - what are you planning to do? A simple plane at the same height of the character could be raycasted to, which you could then move the character to shortly after.

This would prevent the odd drift that you're getting now.